# Why Aviary Maintaining a Cache Image Path? | Android

Tags: android, aviary, adobecreativesdk

I am using **Aviary**, but when i open any image in Aviary then it creates an **cache image path.**

I am passing my own image path but still it creates their new path **(WITH CACHE IMAGE).**

Any suggestions on this.
**Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: Are you by chance using an `http` Uri as the location of your original image when you call `.setData()`?

Comment: NO i am passing SD card file path

Comment: We would need to see your Activity code to troubleshoot any further. In the meantime, you might find [this GitHub repo helpful](https://github.com/CreativeSDK/android-getting-started-samples/tree/master/image-editor-ui).

Answer (score 0):

The Creative SDK Image Editor (formerly Aviary) will do this if you use an `http` Uri as the location of your original image when you call `.setData()`.

As noted in [the Methods section of the Creative SDK Image Editor guide](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html#methods), for the `.setData()` method:

> **`.setData()`**
>
> Sets the input image Uri.
>
> Supported schemes are:
>
> - [scheme_file](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#SCHEME_FILE) (e.g. `file://mnt/sdcard/download/image.jpg`)
> - [scheme_content](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#SCHEME_CONTENT) (e.g. `content://media/external/images/media/112232`)
>
> Note: `http` will work for low-resolution editing only, but it is not a feature that we currently support.

Part of `http` Uri's not being a supported is that the saved image is lower quality and the output Uri is set by the Image Editor.